# Why stoned an ox?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 21:

> 28 When an ox gores a man or a woman to death, the ox shall be **stoned**, and its flesh shall not be eaten, but the owner of the ox shall not be liable.

Why stoned an ox? Why not just kill it by a quicker method?

Comment: Stoning sheds relatively little blood. Could there be significance that the animal dies with "the life" still in it?

Answer (score 6):

Stoning differs from slaughter insofar that it is impossible to tell who's stone is the one caused the actual death. This way the owner has no one to blame for the loss of his ox later.

My understanding is that a large part of Moses's law is clearly motivated by avoiding a division in the tribe. So where there's no human liable to another human, the punishment should ideally not create a new liability.

Comment: Did you mean a 'division' in the tribe (rather than 'derision') ?

Comment: Thank you, a typo indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate grammaplow's perspective, yet I see another aspect here as well.

Stones represent God's law.  The Ten Commandments were written in stone to symbolize their eternal and unchanging nature.  In a sense, stoning was symbolic of having the law thrown at someone, reminiscent of the modern-day idiom for "throwing the book at [someone]."

Murder was punishable, by law, with execution.  A beast who killed a human, such as an ox in this case, was to be lawfully executed.  Within this punishment, a representation is made of Satan's ultimate end, having made himself guilty of the blood of countless humans.

The very fact that stoning would not be the easiest way of euthanizing the beast is what should call our attention to the symbolic value of this act.

Answer (score 1):

> When an ox gores a man or a woman to death, the ox shall be stoned, and its flesh shall not be eaten, but the owner of the ox shall not be liable. (Exodus 21:28)

> When one man's ox butts another's, so that it dies, then they shall sell the live ox and share its price, and the dead beast also they shall share. (Exodus 21:35)

There is a difference between an ox killing another animal, and an ox killing a person. And the difference is also shown in the way they are dealt with.
One should be **stoned** and its meat may not be eaten, but the other should be **sold**.

I think stoning the ox renders its meat less attractive for eating.

The practice of stoning in general also has its reasons (as we see in @Biblasia and @grammaplow's answers), but that's maybe a discussion on its own.

Comment: "*stoning the ox renders its meat less attractive for eating*".  Much more than that. Unless it could be known for certain that it had died by bleeding to death, the meat would be considered unfit for consumption. ¶ In today's slaughterhouses, cattle are stunned with a *blow to the head* before their throats are slit. This is a major factor in making the meat non-kosher, because there's no way of knowing that the blow wouldn't have been fatal.